# 100% container height with footer

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with a page I'm doing.

A Snippet of the code:

```
<div id="header"> // header..
</div>
<div id="content">  // content where ajax is loaded (should be atleast 100% of the site height)
    <!-- ajax -->
</div>
<div id="footer"> //empty atm.

</div>
```

now for the css:

```
#content{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#767670;
    width:800px;
    border-left:1px solid #9F9793;
    border-right:1px solid #9F9793;
    position:relative;
    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/
    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */

}
#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    border-top:1px solid #9F9793;
    border-bottom:1px solid #9F9793;
    background-color:#767670;
}
```

I want the container to be from the header to the footer, I tried to apply the code and tips that I found, yet without success. Appreciating any answers!

Comment: Take a look on this:  http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 1):

```
#content{
height:100%;
}
```

This implies that content div takes 100% of the parent container, which in this case is html.

So write

```
html{
height:100%;
}
```